# Cannot stub arrow function in a class using Sinon

Tags: javascript, typescript, sinon

- Sinon version : v2.0.0-pre.2
- Environment   : Windows 10
- Other libraries you are using: Typescript, babel, mocha, chai

**What did you expect to happen?**

I expected to be able to stub an arrow function in a class.

**What actually happens**

I can't stub an arrow function, however, I can stub the class prototype function.

```
FAILED TESTS:
  ExampleClass tests
    × should stub thisDoesntWork arrow function
      Chrome 52.0.2743 (Windows 10 0.0.0)
    TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property thisDoesntWork as function
        at wrapMethod (webpack:///~/sinon/pkg/sinon.js:3138:0 <- test-bundler.js:7377:21)
        at Object.stub (webpack:///~/sinon/pkg/sinon.js:2472:0 <- test-bundler.js:6711:12)
        at Context.<anonymous> (webpack:///src/stores/sinon.test.ts:22:51 <- test-bundler.js:96197:72)
```

**How to reproduce**

```
export class ExampleClass {
    thisWorks() {
        return 0;
    }

    thisDoesntWork = () => {
        return 0;
    }
}

describe("ExampleClass tests", () => {
    it("should stub thisWorks function", () => {
        let stubFunctionA = sinon.stub(ExampleClass.prototype, "thisWorks");
    });
    it("should stub thisDoesntWork arrow function", () => {
        let stubFunctionB = sinon.stub(ExampleClass, "thisDoesntWork");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used `sinon`, but in their documentation it states for the `sinon.stub` function that it:

> Replaces object.method with a stub function

If you look at the compiled js code of your `ExampleClass`:

```
var ExampleClass = (function () {
    function ExampleClass() {
        this.thisDoesntWork = function () {
            return 0;
        };
    }
    ExampleClass.prototype.thisWorks = function () {
        return 0;
    };
    return ExampleClass;
}());
```

Then you'll see that `ExampleClass.prototype.thisWorks` is defined, but there's no `ExampleClass.thisDoesntWork` definition, not even `ExampleClass.prototype.thisDoesntWork`.

The `thisDoesntWork` method is added only in the constructor (arrow functions aren't really class methods, they are just class members with a function type).

I suspect that this will work:

```
describe("ExampleClass tests", () => {
    it("should stub thisDoesntWork arrow function", () => {
        let stubFunctionB = sinon.stub(new ExampleClass(), "thisDoesntWork");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! adding `new ExampleClass()` properly stubbed "thisDoesntWork".

Comment: How did you get this compiled example? I am using babel online but the compiled javascript is complete different.

Comment: @roll three years passed, i suspect that everything is different now...

Comment: @NitzanTomer another 4 passed and it's really not..